# Setting a breakpoint for when a Java class is loaded in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, classloader, breakpoints

Is there a way to set a breakpoint for when a particular Java class is loaded in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I don't know if it would work, (hence a comment), but I wonder if you could add a static initialization block to your class, and set a breakpoint on that?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am trying to figure out which class loader is loading some particular classes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14364566/7648  I want to know because I'm investigating a problem similar to this: eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/173612 Apparently this can happen when two classes are being loaded by different class loaders (see content linked to for details). I am trying to determine whether that is the case for the problem I'm looking at.

Comment: Similar [question](/q/22148420) for Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. But if you are trying to determine from where a class is first being loaded, you could put a break point in the constructor (or static fields/block) of the class, and look at the stack trace. That should tell you where the first call to the class is being made.

Comment: What I'm really trying to determine is whether two classes are being loaded by the same class loader or by different class loaders.

Comment: Ah. This is a crude way but you could put a logging message with some prefix (i.e. "CLASSLOADER CHECK") and in the constructor log the classloader (`this.getClass().getClassLoader()`). Then grep the log...

Answer (score 3):

In 2016 version it works by setting the breakpoint to the class definition line (`public class YourClass ...`). You don't have to use explicit constructor, it stops when `... new YourClass();` is called.